# Having Javascript talk to Grails for KML

Tags: javascript, grails, openlayers

I have a controller making a rest call to a web service. It responds with a KML file and then I need to take the response and send it to open layers. I get how to make the call from the controller to the web service, but how do I then use that in a .js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting the [openlayers/KML example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html) slightly, where "grails URL" is the URL to your controller/action which returns some KML in the response:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
            {layers: "basic"}
        ),
        new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: **<grails URL>**
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true, 
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2
                })
            })
        })
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-112.169, 36.099),
    zoom: 11
});
```

Obviously, the other configuration (center, zoom etc) you will need to adapt to your own needs.